# What is the correct format for creating the creative of an MPA Advertisement on facebook?

Tags: facebook

I've been trying to create a MPA(multi-product ad) for some time now, but it keeps giving me the following error "Call to action link should be same as link of the post".
I've used the following format:

```
{
  "object_story_spec" => {
    "page_id" => 321954304600161,
    "instagram_actor_id" => "874410812666052",
    "link_data" => {
      "multi_share_optimized" => true,
      "multi_share_end_card" => true,
      "message" => "Test message ad in adset",
      "caption" => nil,
      "link" => "http://www.adwyze.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=ocpm&utm_campaign=TestforJson-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_term=all-MF-18-65-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_content=test_testadinadset-00-CarouselAd-06Dec2017-19h44m&utm_id=2b301660-01c2-4c21-9fe1-06863dbaac92",
      "child_attachments" => [{
        "link" => "http://www.adwyze.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=ocpm&utm_campaign=Test for Json-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_term=all-MF-18-65-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_content=test_test ad in adset-00-CarouselAd-06Dec2017-19h44m&utm_id=2b301660-01c2-4c21-9fe1-06863dbaac92",
        "name" => "TEst ad in adset",
        "description" => nil,
        "picture" => "https://adcreation-m.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1512559029_test.jpg",
        "call_to_action" => {
          "type" => "SHOP_NOW",
          "value" => {
            "link" => "http://www.adwyze.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=ocpm&utm_campaign=TestforJson-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_term=all-MF-18-65-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_content=test_testadinadset-00-CarouselAd-06Dec2017-19h44m&utm_id=2b301660-01c2-4c21-9fe1-06863dbaac92"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "link" => "http://www.adwyze.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=ocpm&utm_campaign=Test for Json-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_term=all-MF-18-65-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_content=test_test ad in adset-00-CarouselAd-06Dec2017-19h44m&utm_id=2b301660-01c2-4c21-9fe1-06863dbaac92",
        "name" => "TEst",
        "description" => nil,
        "picture" => "https://adcreation-m.s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1512559033_test.jpg",
        "call_to_action" => {
          "type" => "SHOP_NOW",
          "value" => {
            "link" => "http://www.adwyze.com?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=ocpm&utm_campaign=TestforJson-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_term=all-MF-18-65-06Dec2017-16h48m&utm_content=test_testadinadset-00-CarouselAd-06Dec2017-19h44m&utm_id=2b301660-01c2-4c21-9fe1-06863dbaac92"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I've made sure that in "child_attachments". "link" and "call_to_action.value.link" have the same value, but I keep getting the same error. I've also tried escaping the links, removing spaces etc. I've been seeing this behaviour since 10 hours or so.

Comment: _“I've made sure that in "child_attachments". "link" and "call_to_action.value.link" have the same value”_ - no, you didn’t actually - they differ in the utm tracking parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Despite's OP incorrect link values in the child_attachment and call_to_action, this has been confirmed by Facebook as a valid bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/310154929502029/
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1909897769263210/

I'm guessing OP was testing a lot of different combinations and this one he posted happened to have different values.

Hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Ya, I was testing a bunch of different combinations, I accidentally messed-up this example here.